# SQL Server using incorrect plan

Tags: sql-server

In our application we have the following tiers for data processing:

- .NET orchestration application that works out which SSIS packages to fire
- SSIS packages that do much of the work and call Stored Procedures
- Stored procedures to perform calculations and read/write data where SSIS data flows are not appropriate

One stored procedure runs in 40 seconds if executed from SSMS, and approximately the same time if the SSIS package is called manually.

If however, the SSIS package is called by the .NET app, then the query takes more than 14 hours to run, and flat lines all processors.

Looking at the execution plans, it seems that if the procedure is run from SSMS or the SSIS package is fired manually and then calls the procedure, SQL Server uses a sensible plan based on current statistics.

However, if the SSIS package is called from the .NET app, then SQL server create a new plan, using totally the wrong statistics. The following things made no difference:

- Updating stats
- Clearing the cache
- Restarting the instance
- Setting WITH RECOMPILE on the procedure execution

We fudged resolution by using a MAXDOP hint in the query, but my question is this:

What would make SQL Server produce a totally different plan, based on totally incorrect statistics when called with the same parameters and same data through the method I described?

Comment: It sounds like parameter sniffing and your assumption that the plan was generated with the same parameters is not correct. If you still have the bad plan look and see what the parameter compiled values and run time values are in the XML. See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) for more.

Comment: When you say "The following things made difference" you mean they helped and you got a good plan afterwards? That was what I was assuming in the comment above.

Comment: @MartinSmith - sorry, typo. Was meant to read "made no difference"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have mostly answered your other questions in your monologue, and the `things that made a difference` are the standard list of things to do to force a recompile after being afflicted by [*parameter sniffing*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mdegre/what-is-parameter-sniffing).

To answer your last question, the one marked `my question is this`:

> What would make SQL Server produce a totally different plan, based on totally incorrect statistics when called with the same parameters and same data through the method I described?

**The answer** is that the [plan cache](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303050650/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2007/01/12/5-0-retrieving-query-plans-from-plan-cache-dmv-s.aspx) is very specific about [SET settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20160411223202/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx) that are in effect on the session that is presenting the query. A different SET setting could need a very different plan, such as the setting `SET ANSI_NULLS`.  Very likely, your connection from SSMS has different settings from what your .Net application.  This is easily verifiable by using SQL Server Profiler to trace for `Existing Connections` and `Login Audits`, which show you the `SET` settings.

The effect is that the *seemingly* same query will result in a `Cache Miss` and a new one has to be created, which will be somewhat based on the parameters being presented to SQL Server for this instance of the query.

Comment: @richrdthekiwi - thanks, the team are investigating this, but I don't understand why the SET options would be different? same machine, .NET guys tell me nothing being passed explicitly in the connection string?

Comment: @PeteCarter - SSMS has a different default for `ARITHABORT` than your application probably does.